# Expected Value of Rewards from Coin Flipping

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-functions

I am struggling with coming up with an approach for the following question (pulled from Assignment 4 from MIT's 6.041 Probability course, which I'm trying to self-study as I realized my probability fundamentals are really weak):

5. Consider a sequence of independent tosses of a biased coin at times t = 0, 1, 2, . . .. On each toss,
   the probability of a ’head’ is p, and the probability of a ’tail’ is 1 − p. A reward of one unit is
   given each time that a ’tail’ follows immediately after a ’head.’ Let R be the total reward paid
   in times 1, 2, . . . , n. Find E[R] and var(R).

So far, this is what I've been able to observe and my thought process (which seems to be too complicated/incorrect). I'd love some advice/line of questioning/poking holes into my logic (without giving away the solution) so that I may come up with the approach myself:

1. We get a reward of 1 unit every time we encounter a 'TH' sequence. Then all coin flips outside of the 'TH' occurences are a sequence of H followed by a sequence of T. ex. HHHTHTTT for 1 'TH' occurence.
2. Given n coin flips, there can be at most floor(n/2) such occurences of this sequence. Then the expected value of the reward, E[R] = $\sum_{x=0}^{n/2} x * p(x)$
3. Then I considered the case x = 0. If there are no 'TH', then this means the sequence of flips must be a sequence of i heads followed by j tails, where i+j = n. Then *p(x = 0)* =  $\sum_{i=0}^n p^i * (1-p)^{(n-i)}$ which is a geometric progression (right?)
4. Obviously the value of p(x=0) doesn't matter since x = 0, but that was the easiest case. Then I tried to find what this would look like for x=1 and so on, but then I would have to consider all the partitions of non 'TH' flips created, and this would get massively complicated, so clearly I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't find another direction.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Expectation is easily read off via Linearity.  If there are $n$ tosses there are $n-1$ places where a $TH$ sequence might start, work out the probability and multiply.  Variance is similar but a little more work since you'll have to consider pairs of starting points.

Comment: There are in fact $n+1$ tosses up to toss $n$ since you start at $0$.  What is not clear to me is whether you asked to look for the expectation and variance for a single pair so $E[R]=(1-p)p$ or for the $n+1$ tosses so $E[R]=n(1-p)p$.  The variance is easy to find in the single pair case but less so for the $n+1$ tosses

Comment: @Henry From my understanding, the question is asking to find the expected number of pairs in n+1 tosses.

Comment: To clarify (since the question doesn't seem to be clear to 3 members): There are n+1 tosses at 0 to n. We consider the total reward, that is the sum of the individual rewards from 1 to n, where we discard 0 since it is impossible to get a reward there. But yes, we could write $R=R_1+\cdots+R_n$ with $R_i$ being the reward at time $i$, and then use linearity as proposed.